# Phonetic understanding of tongue twisters

Tags: phonetics

I like tongue twisters.

Five fine vine weevils 
(plays with W, F and V)

Six sick stick insects 
(plays with S, ST, KT, K and T)

Gran crams clams into clean clam cans 
(plays with R and L and also with M and N)

How many more English sounds can be played with in a tongue tripping way ?

Comment: The state of the art paper on tongue twisters is still Larry Schourup's 1973 "Unique New York Unique New York Unique New York" in _Papers from the 9th Regional Meeting,_ Chicago Linguistic Society, C. Corum _et al_ (eds) pp 587-596.

Comment: @John Lawler: I notice you chose to use no hyphens. I got as far as "...art paper on tongue...." before I realized I had go back and re-parse. Perhaps in some earlier question you explained why hyphens are extraneous in "state of the art" used before a noun?

Comment: They're not needed in speech, so they must be extraneous. Just more unneeded squiggles like Hebrew vowels.